# Need help in Firebase query for this scenario

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have DB structure as
[image: DB Structure]

and my code query is

```
quesRef = myRef.child("questions").orderByChild("timestamp").endAt("120");
```

Ideally as per my understanding all the values whose timestamp is less than 120 should get return, but in my case, almost all the questions are getting returned.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: what you want as result?

Comment: The result must be all the key value pairs whose timestamp is greater than 120, in my case I am getting null

Answer (score 1):

You are querying to an ending value of the string `"120"` instead of the number `120`.

Instead, it should read:

```
quesRef = myRef.child("questions").orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(120);
```

I'm not sure why the timestamp would be as low as 120 anyway, but perhaps that's just for testing purposes?

Comment: I tried , but endAt uses a double value, hence in my case it is not much help  , I need endAt which accepts long.

Comment: When you say you tried, what was the result? I use this method for querying based on timestamp and it works.